# How do we invoke WCF Callback from Class Library?

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

I have implemented `wsDualHttpBinding` with a `Callback` behavior.  This works fine without any issues.

My Service Config

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="MyServiceNamespace" behaviorConfiguration="default">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="MyServiceCoontract" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
 <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

My Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IMQServiceCallBack))]
public interface IMQService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PublishMessage(Message message);
}

public interface IMQServiceCallBack
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MessageAcked(string fileName);

   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MessageNacked(string fileName);
}
```

My Service

```
public class MQService : IMQService
{
    public IMQServiceCallBack CallBack
    {
        get
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMQServiceCallBack>();
        }
    }

    public void PublishMessage(Common.Message message)
    {
        var mqManager = MQManager.GetInstance();
        mqManager.PublishMessage(message);
        CallBack.MessageAcked(message.FileName);
    }
}
```

Callback works fine in principle as per my implementation.  But, my call back invocation should not be coming from my service class but a class library.

When I publish a message using `mqManager.PublishMessage(message)` in a class library, there is already a callback in that library for acknowledgement.

Callback in my `MQManager` class

```
void channel_BasicAcks()
{
    //need to invoke service call back from here
}
```

So, basically when `channel_BasicAcks()` call back is invoked in class library, I need to alert my Service which consumes this library so that service in turn should call back my client.  I'm stuck with the middle step on how to alert my service from the call back method in the class library.  Any direction here would help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

There's no nice way to do it.

**Long answer**

The basic problem is that you can only access the callback channel from within the thread running the WCF service, using OperationContext.Current.

There is a fairly dirty workaround which involves making your service a singleton, storing all the callbacks in a static member within your service instance, and providing some kind of *registration* service operation which clients must call in order to receive callbacks.

Something like

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IMQServiceCallBack))]
public interface IMQService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PublishMessage(Message message);

    [OperationContract]
    void Register();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MQService : IMQService
{
    public static List<CallBack> callbacks;

    public void Register()
    {
        callbacks.Add(OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMQServiceCallBack>());
    }
}
```

You could then call the callback remotely from another part of your app domain. Something like

```
var service = new MQService();
service.callbacks.ForEach((c) => {
    c.MessageAcked(someMessage)
});
```

This is pretty horrible on so many levels to be honest and I would not recommend it for anything other than the most basic applications.

Comment: Yes, I figured there is no way. But, still many times I was defeated when I thought there is no way, SO says there is a way :) I moved my callback interface to the class library, passed my OperationContext to that library so the library itself can invoke call back for clients